# Python: how to deal with several .pyd dependencies with the same name?

Tags: python, import, dependencies, python-sip, pyd

I have in my python workspace two Modules which need sip.pyd
Module1.pyd needs sip.pyd (which implements v 8.0-8.1)
Module2.pyd needs sip.pyd (another file, that implements v6.0)

So I can't just choose the newer one, it doesn't work: I have to keep them both!

```
(RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v6.0 but the fbx module requires API v8.1)
```

How can I import a module in .pyd extension (a python dll, not editable), and specify which sip.pyd to source?

As for a workaround, I manage to do that:

1. One sip.pyd is in my root site-packages location.
2. If I have to import the module that need the other sip.pyd, I remove root path form sys.path, and I append the precise folder path where the other sip.pyd are.
3. I can import my Module and restore previous sys.path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a piece of code needing both files at once. I'd recommend the following:

- install both files in 2 separate directories (call them e.g. `sip-6.0` and `sip-8.0`), that you'll place in `site-packages/`
- write a `sip_helper.py` file with code looking like

sip_helper.py contents:

```
import sys
import re
from os.path import join, dirname
def install_sip(version='6.0'):
    assert version in ('6.0', '8.0'), "unsupported version"
    keep = []
    if 'sip' in sys.modules:
       del sys.modules['sip']
    for path in sys.path:
        if not re.match('.*sip\d\.\d', path):
            keep.append(path)
    sys.path[:] = keep # remove other paths
    sys.path.append(join(dirname(__file__), 'sip-%s' % version))
```

- put sip_helper.py in site_packages (the parent directory of the sip-6.0 and sip-8.0 directories)
- call `sip_helper.install_sip` at the startup of your programs

Comment: Thank you, it works very well!
And if I have, in the same code, to toggle between sip i can do:

try:
    import ModuleX
except:
    sip_helper.install_sip()
import ModuleX

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualEnv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) is done to handle those case.

> virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

Using virtualenv, you will be able to create 2 environements, one with the sip.pyd in version 8.x another in version 6.0

Comment: Thank you for this tips !
as I have used the other solution, i found VirtualEnv very interesting!
I'm sure I will use it somewhere else, sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that works (if a module's name has to match its contents), but can't you just rename them to `sip6.pyd` resp. `sip8.pyd` and then do

```
if need6:
    import sip6 as sip
else:
    import sip8 as sip
```

?